# Copy Worksheet, rename sheets based off range, and edit copied sheets based off range

Tags: vba, excel, copy

Essentially my goal is to  :

1. create copies based off a template and rename them based off a list of names(i got this part figured out)
2. change two cells in the copies based off another range of cells

My code

```
 Sub CopyInfoSheetandInsert()
 Dim rcell As Range
 Dim hcell As Range
 Dim Info As Worksheet
 Set Info = ActiveSheet
 For Each rcell In Range("B2:B30")
     If rcell.Value <> "" Then
           Sheets("Team Member (2)").Copy After:=Sheets("Info")
           Sheets("Team Member (3)").Name = rcell.Value
     End If
 Next rcell
 End Sub
```

What I'm having trouble with is where to add my second range and how to change a cell based off it.

Comment: Can you specify which is the *second range* and which cells you want to change?

Comment: The second range is on the info A2:A30 and the cell being changed is E:2. i sourced the second cell to read off of E:2 so now i only need to change that one cell.

Comment: I am almost sure it cant be something as simple as `Sheets("Team Member (2)").Range("E2").Value = something` ... But I fail to figure out what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: ^ that's originally what i tried but got an error

Answer (score 0):

When you copy the 'template' worksheet to the position after the **Info** worksheet, you know immediately that its [Worksheet.Index property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836415.aspx) will be one greater than the `.Index` of the Info worksheet. Use this in a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to identify the new worksheet and perform all operations there.

```
Sub CopyInfoSheetandInsert()
    Dim rcell As Range, hcell As Range, Info As Worksheet

    Set Info = ActiveSheet

    For Each rcell In Info.Range("B2:B30")
        If rcell.Value <> "" Then
            Sheets("Team Member (2)").Copy After:=Sheets("Info")
            With Sheets(Sheets("Info").Index + 1)
                .Name = rcell.Value
                .Range("A1") = "this is the new worksheet"  '<~~perform the other operations like this
                .Range("A2") = Info.Range("Z99").Value  '<~~cannot reference Info as ActiveSheet anymore. Need direct worksheet reference like this.
                .Range("A3") = rcell.Offset(0, 1).Value '<~~you can still use rcell as a reference point for other information
            End With
        End If
    Next rcell
End Sub
```

Alternately, once the new worksheet has been named you could use the Worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx) before you loop to a new `rcell`.

```
    Set Info = ActiveSheet
    For Each rcell In Info.Range("B2:B30")
        If rcell.Value <> "" Then
            Sheets("Team Member (2)").Copy After:=Sheets("Info")
            Sheets("Team Member (3)").Name = rcell.Value
            With Sheets(rcell.Value)
                .Range("A1") = "this is the new worksheet"  '<~~perform the other operations like this
                .Range("A2") = Info.Range("Z99").Value  '<~~cannot reference Info as ActiveSheet anymore. Need direct worksheet reference like this.
                .Range("A3") = rcell.Offset(0, 1).Value '<~~you can still use rcell as a reference point for other information
            End With
        End If
    Next rcell
```

Remember that the current [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is going to change to the new worksheet when you make a copy. If you are retrieving the information from the Info worksheet (the original ActiveSheet) then you need to use the worksheet object reference you `Set` before the copying process began. Since the loop established the range of cells on the Info worksheet when the `For ... Next` commenced, you can still use `rcell` as a reference point on the Info worksheet.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth explanation, it not only helps me solve my problem but this information helps me further my VBA skillset. Showing multiple approaches to handling the problem was greatly appreciated. I will definitely be studying this even after it completed my function.